# How can I find video files on an internal IIS web server? Explorer not showing anything

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-8

I've been tasked with taking (what I think are) .WMV files and uploading them all to Vimeo. However, I cannot seem to even find the files. The file paths are kind of being "obscured" so to speak by JavaScript: hovering over the video links only shows "javascript:void(0)" and similarly when I inspect element it just shows: "onclick="javascript:window.open('../../Main/Help/HelpCenterVideoPopup.aspx?PublicID=thisIsALongString...', 'height=530,width=880, etc, etc,"

The thing is that these WMV files barely play in IE on Win7 and in Chrome on Win10, forget, they won't play at all: pop-up windows just displays "plugin is not supported" and apparently there *is* no WMV plug-in for Chrome.

I searched all through C:\Inetpub\wwwRoot\SiteInQuestion on the IIS web server...and found no video files at all. I even ran a scan via TreeSize....but no .WMV files are there. TreeSize did turn up some .AVI files, but less than 4 MB's of them, so that cannot be the right files. There are over 40 videos hosted on the site. I did check HTML in the underlying .ASPX website file too, but it just makes no sense to me. There are no paths there.

So how can I find where these videos files actually live? Perhaps the underlying JavaScript file? I know enough about web dev to be dangerous, but this is just beyond me. Thanks in advance.

Lastly, I opened the .JS file that is referenced in the .ASPX website HTML code, but it is just a lot of (what is to me) indecipherable text.

Comment: You have to find the original developers for assistance. Maybe they saved the video files in a database, or other format. Without checking the code, you won't find the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @LexLi. What about the "virtual paths" in IIS, could they be helpful? I'm not sure who the dev is that wrote this website or if he/she is even still with the company.

Comment: Find a guy who knows .NET/ASP.NET in your company. If he/she has enough experience, then the code can be understood in a few minutes/hours, much quicker than your current approach of asking it over the internet, as readers won't be able to see the code nor the application.

Comment: Take firefox, open developer tools' network tab, and click on a movie link. What url is requested?

Comment: Thank you, @GerardH.Pille!! This got me the info I need! :) If you'd like to write that up as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take firefox, open developer tools' network tab, and click on a movie link. What url is requested?